# AWS Terraform , Cannot find upgrade path from 5.7.38 to 5.6 ,GitLab CI Runners faild InvalidParameterCombinatin

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws, gitlab-ci-runner

Everytime I run the pipline , GitLab CI Runners faild the job with the following error message ::

```
│ Error: Error modifying DB Instance legacy-dms: InvalidParameterCombination: Cannot find upgrade path from 5.7.38 to 5.6.
│   status code: 400, request id: e7740193-bf98-464c-a1b3-4124d7f5d909
│ 
│   with module.db.module.db_instance.aws_db_instance.this[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/db/modules/db_instance/main.tf line 45, in resource "aws_db_instance" "this":
│   45: resource "aws_db_instance" "this" {
│ 
╵
```

**Terraform hcl File :**

```
inputs = {

  # Identifier is name in AWS and should be unique in the account
  identifier = "test-dms"
  # Name is actual DB name (doesn't need to be unique)
  name = "PNRQ"

  # Set the following carefully on valid RDS values:
  engine         = "mysql"
  engine_version = "5.6"
  # One year old bug, creating option groups when the default should be used
  # So we have to explicitly set it to the default
  # https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds/issues/272
  # https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds/issues/188
  option_group_name = "default:mysql-5-6"
  port              = 3306

  # Change these depending on size/load requirements of the DB and environment
  instance_class    = "db.t3.micro"
  allocated_storage = 20
  multi_az          = false

  # Boilerplate for VPC
  vpc_id         = dependency.vpc.outputs.vpc_id
  vpc_subnet_ids = dependency.vpc.outputs.private_subnets
  allowed_security_groups = [
    # Allow EKS connection
    dependency.eks.outputs.worker_security_group_id,
    # Allow infra runner connection
    dependency.infra_ci.outputs.runner_sg_id
  ]
}
```

We have an aws RDS Instance name:  test-dms Engine with version 5.7.38.

and I have already updated the ACM certificate associated with this account.

Can anyone assist me in resolving this problem? I would greatly appreciate any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you mentioned an ACM certificate since it has nothing to do with any of the code, or the error message, in your question.

As for the error you are getting, you have a MySQL 5.7 RDS server running in AWS, and you have Terraform configured to deploy a MySQL 5.6 server. The Terraform error is telling you that you are asking it to downgrade the server to a previous version, and AWS doesn't allow you to do that. You need to update your Terraform code to specify MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Does the engine_version = "5.7.38" and option_group_name = "default:mysql-5-7" changes would work or do I need to specify another specific version here ? Is this change going to affect anything with the existing RDS instance we have?

Comment: That looks like it would work, but why are you posting here asking these questions when simply running `terraform plan` and looking at the output would answer your questions and concerns? If `terraform plan` doesn't show any changes to your RDS instance then obviously there would be no affect to your existing RDS instances. The problem is you modified the RDS instance outside of Terraform, and now you need to bring Terraform up-to-date with the changes you made.